# Exclude crashlytics from twitter fabric

Tags: android, twitter, gradle, twitter-fabric

I would like to exclude crashlytics from fabric because when I try to integrate the sdk following the instructions
[here](https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/android/integrate), I get the following error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:fabricCleanupResourcesDebug'.
> Crashlytics Developer Tools error.
```

My goal is to be able to compose a tweet with [this](https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/android/compose) guide which I believe, needs the previous plugin to be installed first. Adding `maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/repo' }` only doesn't work and result in a not found library exception.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you but I found a way to get it working by using the following directives in my build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
    classpath "io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+"
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.+'
compile ('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:1.1.1@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
compile ('com.twitter.sdk.android:tweet-composer:0.7.2@aar')
{
    transitive = true;
}
compile project(':library')
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Mike from Fabric here.

Using the Twitter Kit will allow you to bypass that guide, but use:

```
 maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
```

instead of /repo to get the library.

Comment: I don't know if things have changed since this answer but in any case the error persists despite using the /public URL. That is, crashlytics is still included in the build.